# How to use wild card in admin routing in laravel 5

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, wildcard-expansion

I am using code that is below for admin routing in laravel.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
Route::get('/', 'Admin\AdminController@home');
Route::get('/users/userList', 'Admin\UserController@userList');
Route::get('/users/detail', 'Admin\UserController@detail');
Route::get('/posts/view', 'Admin\PostController@view');
Route::get('/posts/edit', 'Admin\PostController@edit');
Route::get('/posts/add', 'Admin\PostController@add');
});
```

This is working fine for me. But when I add new functions in code for that I have to write routing in routes file. For example: If I want to add edit functionality in users controller, for that I have to add new route like .

**Route::get('/users/edit', 'Admin\UserController@edit');**

So I have to add routing for each function.

I want to know **How to use wild card for admin routing** so that I have to write routing only for controller not for each function for example.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
Route::get('/', 'Admin\AdminController@home');
Route::get('/users/:any', 'Admin\UserController@:any');
Route::get('/posts/:any', 'Admin\PostsController@:any');  
});
```

wild card replace the function name, and auto ridirect to that function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [implicit controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers) that will do what you need.

First declare a route for your implicit controller

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

Then, on your controller, you have to follow a convention for naming your routes with HTTP verbs used to access them (*get* for GET, *post* for POST, *any* for both)

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        //
    }

    public function postProfile()
    {
        //
    }

    public function anyLogin()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

A note about composed method name from documentation

> If your controller action contains multiple words, you may access the action using "dash" syntax in the URI. For example, the following controller action on our `UserController` would respond to the `users/admin-profile` URI:
>
> ```
> public function getAdminProfile() {}
> ```